# Как прижать подвал в адпаптивном макете

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, адаптивная-верстка

*footer* страницы никак не ограничен по высоте, а при уменьшении экрана содержимое подвала перемещается вниз. Как сделать чтобы на всех экранах он был прижат, но при этом вел себя правильно(н-р не перекрывал контент)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  flex: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>flex</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">flex-content</div>
   <div class="footer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
    <br />
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus illo distinctio, ex fugit similique est! Itaque atque, pariatur necessitatibus amet. Illo incidunt, voluptatibus sunt voluptatem, dolorum sequi vitae eligendi fugit, dicta explicabo, sapiente tenetur unde saepe! Similique culpa, deleniti, quibusdam architecto, dignissimos placeat quae accusantium, libero voluptatem officiis repudiandae rerum!
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант (высота футера определяется автоматически)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.page-content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.page-footer {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <section class="page-content">
        content
    </section>
    <footer class="page-footer">
        footer
    </footer>
</div>
```