# прижать Footer к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, не могу прикрутить футер к низу страницы, он постоянно позиционируется возле лого.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 ;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
  body { 
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 background: url('../img/bg-body.png') no-repeat 50% 0 #0e0e0e;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 font: 15px/4  Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0 0;
 
}

.wrapper{
 width: 1000px;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width: 100%; 
 margin:0px auto;
}
.wrapper{ 
 position: relative; 
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 137px;
}

.logo{ 
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
z-index: 10;
}

.Nav-left{
 float: left;
margin: 30px 0 0 -350px;
}

.Nav-left li{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}

.Nav-left li a{
 color:#000000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold; 

}
.Nav-left li a:hover{
  color:#0582fb;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff; 
}

.Nav-left li a:active{ 
 color:#0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
.Nav-left ul li{
 position: relative; 
}
 .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  left: -20px;
  top:100%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

li:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
}
 .submenu  li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .submenu  li a{
  line-height: 45px;+
 }




.Nav-right li a:active{ 
 color:#0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
.Nav-right {
 position: relative; 
 float: right;
margin: 5px -430px 0 0;
}

.Nav-right li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 25px;
}


.Nav-right li a {
 color:#000000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.Nav-right li a:hover{
 color: #0582fb;
}

.Nav-right li.current a{
 color: #0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}

.info {
 font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: Medium;
position: absolute; 
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
top: 120px;
left: -380px;
 float: left;
}
.infobg{
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 top: 110px;
 left: -400px;
}

.sliderbg {
 z-index: 1;
 background: #fff no-repeat; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 190px ;
 width:910px;
 height:290px;
 left: -330px; 
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 890px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider input[name="switch"] {
  display: none;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -15px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #2f363c;
  background-color: #738290;
}

#btn1:checked~.switch label[for="btn1"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn2:checked~.switch label[for="btn2"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn3:checked~.switch label[for="btn3"] {
  background-color: white;
}

.slider-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 300%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slides img {
  width: 890px;
  height: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#btn1:checked~slider-inner slides {
  transform: translate(0);
}

#btn2:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-680px);
}

#btn3:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-1360px);
}

.bgsl{ 
 z-index: 1;
 background: #fff no-repeat; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 285px ;
 width:1100px;
 height:240px;
 left: -420px;
}

.infobag{
background: url('../img/infobg.png');
position: absolute;
top: 525px;
width: 1101px;
height: 430px;
left: -421px;
}
.infobagcnt{
 position:absolute;
top:525px;
width: 1101px;
height: 100%;
left: -421px;
}


h1{
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

h2{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
h3{
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
}
.video{
 margin: 0 0 25px 80px;
}

.infob{
 font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: Medium;
position: absolute; 
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
top: 90px;
left: 590px;
 float: left;
}
.infotren{
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 955px; 
 width: 1101px;
 height: 570px;
 left: -420px;
 }

.pol{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif');  margin: 25px 0 -15px 0; width: 100%; height: 3px;}
.round {
    border-radius: 100px; /* Радиус скругления */
    border: 3px solid #a2a2a2; /* Параметры рамки */
    }

.blc-inftren{
position: relative;
top: -150px;
}



.inftren{
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: -55px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;

}

.inftren:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.pol1{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 

 margin: 25px 0 -15px 10%; 
 width: 80%; height: 3px;}
 .pol2{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 

 margin: 350px 0 -15px 0; 
 width: 100%; height: 3px;}

.inftren1{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 145px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren1:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren2{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 345px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren2:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.inftren3{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 145px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren3:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren4{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 545px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren4:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren5{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90px;
 left: 745px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren5:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.fi{
font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: medium;
top: 200px;

}
.btnc{
 position: relative;
 top: 260px;
 left: 445px;

}
.btn {
 position: absolute;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4398ef), color-stop(1, #0c7df9) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #4398ef 5%, $0c7df9 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4398ef', endColorstr='#0c7df9');
 background-color:#0c7df9;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
 border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
 border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 text-indent:0;
 border:1px solid #84bbf3;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-style:normal;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 width:200px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}
.btn:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #80b5ea), color-stop(1, #4398ef) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #80b5ea 5%, #4398ef 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0c7df9', endColorstr='#4398ef');
 background-color:#80b5ea;
}.btn:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}

.infcrd{
 position: relative;
 top: 1430px;
}

.bgcrd{

background: url('../img/cartbg.png');
height: 300px;
width: 1100px;
top: 95px;
left: -420px;
position: absolute;
}
.otz{
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
 top: 1680px;
 left: -420px;
 height: 300px;
 width: 1100px;

}
.pol3{
 position: absolute;
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 
z-index: 10;
 margin: 50px 0 -15px 0; 
 width: 100%; height: 3px;}

.infotz{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;left: 490px;
}
.box_in{
background: #5F9EA0;
width:1101px;
margin: 0 0 -249px 0;
padding-bottom:249px;
}

.footer{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:100px;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: #000;
 width:1101px;
 height: 249px;
}
.ftbg{
background: url('../img/footer_pic.png');
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 249px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
{headers}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{THEME}/css/style.css"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{THEME}/css/engine.css"> 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:500,500i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
<body>
{AJAX}
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header>

   <ul class="Nav-left">
    <li>
    <a href="#" title="">О нас</a>     
       <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ФОТО</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ВИДЕО</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ПАРТНЕРЫ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ВАКАНСИИ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Расписание</a></li>

   </ul>
   <div class="logo"> 
   <a href="#"><img src="{THEME}/img/logo.png" width="250" height="110"> </a></div>

   <ul class="Nav-right">
    <li><a href="#">Стоимость</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
   
   <div class="infobg"><a href="#"><img src="{THEME}/img/address_nav_bg.png" width="15" height="20"></a></div>
   <span class="info"><br></span>

<div class="bgsl"></div>
<div class="sliderbg">
 <div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3">
  
  <div class="switch">
    <label for="btn1"></label>
    <label for="btn2"></label>
    <label for="btn3"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Art_exo-02-small-680x340.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Concept_Art_Thief_01-680x340.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Concept_Art_Thief_07-680x340.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>

<div class="infobagcnt">
{info}{content}

</div>

<div class="footer">
 
 <div class="ftbg">
 
 
   </div>

</div></div>

  </header>


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681271/Как-прижать-подвал-в-адпаптивном-макете/681341#681341

Answer (score -1):

Код запустить не удалось из-за вставок {} и внешних файлов.
Обратите внимание на то, что открывающие HTML-теги не всегда в Вашем коде соответствуют закрывающим HTML-тегам. Настоятельно советую пропустить Ваш HTML-код через валидатор https://validator.w3.org/.
Если необходим фиксированный футер внизу страницы необходимо использовать следующий стиль:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Результат:

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 ;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
  body { 
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 background: url('../img/bg-body.png') no-repeat 50% 0 #0e0e0e;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 font: 15px/4  Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 0 0;
 
}

.wrapper{
 width: 1000px;
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width: 100%; 
 margin:0px auto;
}
.wrapper{ 
 position: relative; 
 width: 250px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 137px;
}

.logo{ 
position: absolute;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
z-index: 10;
}

.Nav-left{
 float: left;
margin: 30px 0 0 -350px;
}

.Nav-left li{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}

.Nav-left li a{
 color:#000000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold; 

}
.Nav-left li a:hover{
  color:#0582fb;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff; 
}

.Nav-left li a:active{ 
 color:#0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
.Nav-left ul li{
 position: relative; 
}
 .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  left: -20px;
  top:100%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
}

li:hover .submenu{
 display: block;
}
 .submenu  li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .submenu  li a{
  line-height: 45px;+
 }




.Nav-right li a:active{ 
 color:#0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
.Nav-right {
 position: relative; 
 float: right;
margin: 5px -430px 0 0;
}

.Nav-right li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 25px;
}


.Nav-right li a {
 color:#000000;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.Nav-right li a:hover{
 color: #0582fb;
}

.Nav-right li.current a{
 color: #0582fb;
 text-decoration: underline; 
}

.info {
 font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: Medium;
position: absolute; 
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
top: 120px;
left: -380px;
 float: left;
}
.infobg{
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 top: 110px;
 left: -400px;
}

.sliderbg {
 z-index: 1;
 background: #fff no-repeat; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 190px ;
 width:910px;
 height:290px;
 left: -330px; 
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 890px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider input[name="switch"] {
  display: none;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -15px 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #2f363c;
  background-color: #738290;
}

#btn1:checked~.switch label[for="btn1"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn2:checked~.switch label[for="btn2"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn3:checked~.switch label[for="btn3"] {
  background-color: white;
}

.slider-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 300%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slides img {
  width: 890px;
  height: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#btn1:checked~slider-inner slides {
  transform: translate(0);
}

#btn2:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-680px);
}

#btn3:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-1360px);
}

.bgsl{ 
 z-index: 1;
 background: #fff no-repeat; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 285px ;
 width:1100px;
 height:240px;
 left: -420px;
}

.infobag{
background: url('../img/infobg.png');
position: absolute;
top: 525px;
width: 1101px;
height: 430px;
left: -421px;
}
.infobagcnt{
 position:absolute;
top:525px;
width: 1101px;
height: 100%;
left: -421px;
}


h1{
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}

h2{
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
}
h3{
 font-size: 27px;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: center;
}
.video{
 margin: 0 0 25px 80px;
}

.infob{
 font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: Medium;
position: absolute; 
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
top: 90px;
left: 590px;
 float: left;
}
.infotren{
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 955px; 
 width: 1101px;
 height: 570px;
 left: -420px;
 }

.pol{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif');  margin: 25px 0 -15px 0; width: 100%; height: 3px;}
.round {
    border-radius: 100px; /* Радиус скругления */
    border: 3px solid #a2a2a2; /* Параметры рамки */
    }

.blc-inftren{
position: relative;
top: -150px;
}



.inftren{
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: -55px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;

}

.inftren:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.pol1{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 

 margin: 25px 0 -15px 10%; 
 width: 80%; height: 3px;}
 .pol2{
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 

 margin: 350px 0 -15px 0; 
 width: 100%; height: 3px;}

.inftren1{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 145px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren1:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren2{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 345px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren2:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}

.inftren3{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 145px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren3:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren4{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 120px;
 left: 545px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren4:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.inftren5{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90px;
 left: 745px ;
 margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 180px;
}
.inftren5:hover{
 width: 180px;
 height: 280px;
 background: #0c7df9;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.fi{
font: 90% 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: medium;
top: 200px;

}
.btnc{
 position: relative;
 top: 260px;
 left: 445px;

}
.btn {
 position: absolute;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #dcecfb;
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4398ef), color-stop(1, #0c7df9) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #4398ef 5%, $0c7df9 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4398ef', endColorstr='#0c7df9');
 background-color:#0c7df9;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
 border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
 border-top-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
 text-indent:0;
 border:1px solid #84bbf3;
 display:inline-block;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-style:normal;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 width:200px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
}
.btn:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #80b5ea), color-stop(1, #4398ef) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #80b5ea 5%, #4398ef 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0c7df9', endColorstr='#4398ef');
 background-color:#80b5ea;
}.btn:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}

.infcrd{
 position: relative;
 top: 1430px;
}

.bgcrd{

background: url('../img/cartbg.png');
height: 300px;
width: 1100px;
top: 95px;
left: -420px;
position: absolute;
}
.otz{
 background: #fff;
 position: relative;
 top: 1680px;
 left: -420px;
 height: 300px;
 width: 1100px;

}
.pol3{
 position: absolute;
 background: url('../img/polos.gif'); 
z-index: 10;
 margin: 50px 0 -15px 0; 
 width: 100%; height: 3px;}

.infotz{
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;left: 490px;
}
.box_in{
background: #5F9EA0;
width:1101px;
margin: 0 0 -249px 0;
padding-bottom:249px;
}

.footer{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top:100px;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: #f00;
 width:1101px;
 height: 249px;
}
.ftbg{
background: url('../img/footer_pic.png');
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 249px;
}

header {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>
  <ul class="Nav-left">
   <li>
    <a href="#" title="">О нас</a>     
    <ul class="submenu">
     <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ФОТО</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ВИДЕО</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ПАРТНЕРЫ</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">ВАКАНСИИ</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Расписание</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="logo"> 
   <a href="#"><img src="{THEME}/img/logo.png" width="250" height="110" alt="Какая-то картинка"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="Nav-right">
   <li><a href="#">Стоимость</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Акции</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="infobg">
   <a href="#"><img src="{THEME}/img/address_nav_bg.png" width="15" height="20" alt="Ещё какая-то картинка"></a>
  </div>
  <span class="info"><br></span>
  <div class="bgsl"></div>
  <div class="sliderbg">
   <div class="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
    <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3">
    <div class="switch">
     <label for="btn1"></label>
     <label for="btn2"></label>
     <label for="btn3"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-inner">
     <div class="slides">
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Art_exo-02-small-680x340.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Concept_Art_Thief_01-680x340.jpg"/>
      <img src="http://conceptartworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Mathieu_Latour-Duhaime_Concept_Art_Thief_07-680x340.jpg"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="infobagcnt">
   {info}{content}
  </div>
 </header>
</div>
<div class="footer">
 <div class="ftbg">
 </div>
</div>
```

В HTML-коде обратите внимание на то, что footer перемещён из header'а и wrapper'а в body для упрощения.
В CSS код добавил только 2 последних стиля, всё остальное без изменений.
В случае, если футер собой загородит другой блок, то для этого блока необходимо применить свойство padding-bottom со значением, равным высоте футера.